# How can I tell setup.py for py2app to put data folders in the Contents folder instead of the Resources folder?

Tags: python, macos, setup.py, py2app

My Python program has a number of *data file folders.*

In an *sdist* distribution these folders are all children of the *project root folder.*

In a **py2app** distribution, these folders wind up as children of the **Resources** folder.

However when tuning the macOS app created by **py2app**, Python keeps looking for these data folders as children of the **Contents** folder.

When they are in the Resources folder instead, the program can't find them and fails.

I've manually moved the data folders to the **Contents** folder, and then my Python program works as a macOS App.

**Question:** How can I tell **setup.py** for **py2app** so that these folders all wind up in the **Contents** folder instead of the **Resources** folder? (or alternatively, how do I tell python to look for these data folders in **Resources** instead?)

*There doesn't seem to be an example in the py2app examples folder or documentation that covers this case.*